# UML Sequence Diagramm : Several Alternative / Error flows on single Message

Tags: uml

For a UML SEQUENCE DIAGRAM :

Can I create **several** Alternative flows and Exceptional (Error) flows **on a Single Message** (any type of message like reflexive, self message or regular message) ?

For instance : 
Let's say the system (to be automated) is a Public Phone(PP)
There are 2 actors : the client (or User) and the PP (the system)

*Message A* (regular message) From Client to PP : The client enter some change / bill in the device ;

*Message B* (reflexive message) : The PP verifies that the money entered (coins, bills ...) is authentic (i.e. not fake) AND is greater than the minimal amount to make a call.

So for Message B, there can be at least 2 alternative flows (fake money, not enough money...) and 1 Error (or Exceptional) flow (i.e The client definitely failing to meet the requirements after 3 trials)

Correct me if I'm wrong but I know that the alternative case can say " go to step (or message) x forward or backward " in the nominal (normal) flow of event. So I need alternative / error flows to deal with exceptions.

**So To reformulate my question with this example**, can I add several alternative / error flown on Message B ( or message A if needed) ?  (and this will be a little comment next to the reflexive arrow of Message B)

[image]

A1 : Alternative flow 1
A2 : Alternative flow 2
E1 : Error flow

And A1, A2, E1 will be described textually but not with the alt or opt UML formalism

Comment: Please provide more context. What you are asking is unclear.

Comment: @JimL. For instance, lets says the system is a Public Phone (PP).  The User (only actor here)  enters some change / bill into the device (PP). Then the PP verifies 2 things : the authenticity of the money (is it real coins / bills) and the minimum amount required to make a call. My question is for if these things are not verified. Can I add 2 alternatives flows (one for amount not respected and the other for fake change) and  one Exceptional case (for the user definitely not succed meeting the requirements after several trials) ?

Comment: I can't tell which type of diagram you have in mind yet.

Comment: @JimL. Ohh yes I forgot to say. A SEQUENCE DIAGRAM...

Comment: How about clarifying your original question now?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I did as you asked

Comment: @JimL. I edited the original question. Could you take a look at it ?

Comment: @ThomasKilian Please see the image I added in my OP

Comment: That's exactly the purpose of the alt-fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: no, you can't. In (very) former UML versions there was a possibility to branch messages (there's a [quite recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060968/uml-sequence-diagram-message-branching) about this). But that has been abandoned.

Instead you may use fragments with `[alt]` to show the different variants.

[image]

Comment: Please see the image I added in my OP

Comment: it's enough to comment here. I'll see that. Just imagine that Object1 receives the "Enter money" and then alternatively send O2 or O3 (or does other self-message voodoo).

Comment: Yeah then with that said... do u mean that my picture is as OK as yours is  (in which cas I could add as many A1, A2, .... , An for the self-message) ?

Comment: I have update my picture as well. The alt could be narrowed to start below the receiving message.

Comment: You still haven't told me if the "formalism" of my picture is correct (yes / no ) ?  Plus one more question. With the alt fragment, how can I represent "go to step number n" (and that step n is outside the alt fragment prior to it or after it) --> For instance If [cond 2] then restart the sequence at step 2 (let's say there are 5 steps before the alt fragment)

Comment: a) you picture is formally correct. b) use the `[cond]` guards to tell which step to take.

Comment: You are a life-saver bro. a) and b) totally satisfy me. Thank you Very much. Problem solved.